# AngularJS ng-repeat + ng-click+ dynamic filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm newbie in AngularJS and I've got this prob here that I guess it's may be simple but I couldn't shoot it down yet

I've got a filter garageFilter who searches a number from an array then, I create a li tag  dynamic with ng-repeat from an Obj []  that I created throught an input[type:number] field.

Each li tag  should have a ng-click event with this garageFilter filter and when I clicked on this li tag it has to search an element according to an item number  in the filter.
I've already have this filter working well with a li tag  element in the view but this one is not created dynamicly as the others one that I need

```
<li data-ng-click="garageFilter={level:3}">Level 3</li>
```

for the dynamic li tag  I've tried this

```
<li data-ng-repeat="level in levelNum track by $index" ng-click="garageFilter={level:{{level}}">Level {{level}}</li>
```

and the html creates this `<li data-ng-repeat="level in levelNum track by $index" ng-click="garageFilter={level:5}" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Level 5</li>`

but the filter doesn't work..

can anyone help me out?? please
Thank you guys!

Comment: `<li data-ng-repeat="lvl in levelNum track by $index" ng-click="garageFilter={level:lvl}">Level {{lvl}}</li>`.

Comment: Hello Michael, it doesn't work that way.. it does not make the fetch or the filter on click

Comment: you were almost right Michael, just one thing left, passing it by as a function; thanks anyway

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, it might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching around, I hit the right way. As I read:

> the problem is because the ng-repeat create a new scope for each
>   iteration. You are writing on the iteration scope

so the best way to face that is creating a function instead of the manual assignment

in my case:

in the app

```
 $scope.myGarageFilter = function(value){
      $scope.garageFilter = {level:value};
    }
```

html

```
 <span ng-repeat="lvl in levelNum">
    <li ng-click="myGarageFilter(lvl.num)">Level {{lvl.num}}</li>
 </span>
```

instead of :

```
<li ng-click="garageFilter={level:4}">Level 4</li>
```